# Is there a term for a prefix that does not change the meaning of a word?

Tags: significado, prefixos

The greek prefix a- usually means "without", "not" or "absence of".

- fônico - afônico
- rítmico - arrítmico
- gramatical - agramatical
- simetria - assimetria

We can note, however, that several verbs have gotten the prefix a- without any change in meaning. Both forms are correct even though one of them may be used more often than the other:

- rebentar - arrebentar
- soprar - assoprar
- plainar - aplainar
- moldar - amoldar
- perrear - aperrear
- etc.

In all these cases, the prefix is certainly not the "greek prefix".

My question: **Is there a term for a prefix (any prefix) that does not change the meaning of a word?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O termo é prefixo **protético** ([ref](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/781)):

> Existem outros prefixos na língua com esta função de reforço. São os chamados prefixos protéticos, porque não acrescentam valores semânticos às palavras às quais se apõem (ex.: amostrar, assoprar).

Said Ali fala também de **sentido positivo ou pleonástico** a respeito do prefixo *des*, na *Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguesa* (grafia original):

> 1262. Fenômeno lingüístico de outra ordem é o emprêgo de *des-* com sentido positivo, ou pleonástico, resultante não da fusão de elementos latinos, mas da confusão de elementos já romanizados. É aliás extremamente diminuto o número de vocábulos destoutra espécie; foram creados depois de constituído o idioma, e usam-se, quase todos, como meras variantes de outras formações: *desinquieto* e *inquieto*; *desaliviar* e *aliviar*, *desfarelar* e *esfarelar*; *descalvado* e *escalvado*, *descampado* e *escampado* e alguns mais.

Comment: Interessante: com relação à referência dada, em pt-BR, "*destrocar*" jamais seria usado como reforço de *trocar*, mas sim com o significado de "*desfazer a troca*".

Comment: @stafusa Sim, esse uso [está marcado](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/destrocar) como limitado a Portugal.

Comment: Thank you very much.  A short paragraph in English would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix `a` can also come from the latin *ad*, which as an adverb [means](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=ad) "to, towards". That [is supposed to be](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/pergunta/etimologia-232/) the `a` in the word *assoprar* and, I believe, also in the word *aonde* ("to where").

Words like *juntar* and *ajuntar* are probably not perfect synonyms, thus the prefix **is** changing the meaning of the word, even if in some examples the distinction has been lost (e.g., arguably *soprar* and *assoprar*). When a prefix doesn't bring a change in meaning, it's called (see Artefacto's [answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5117/2764)) [*prothetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothesis_(linguistics)).

---

### Portuguese

O prefixo `a` pode também vir do latim *ad*, que, como advérbio, [significa](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=ad) "para, em direção a". Essa [seria](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/pergunta/etimologia-232/) o `a` da palavra "assoprar" e, creio o da palavra "aonde" (="para onde").

Palavras como *juntar* e *ajuntar* provavelmente não são sinônimos perfeitos, portanto o prefixo **está** alterando o significado da palavra, ainda que a distinção tenha se perdido em alguns exemplos (e.g., *soprar* e *assoprar*). Quando um prefixo não causa uma alteração de significado, ele é chamado (veja a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5117/2764) do Artefacto) [*protético*](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/781).

Comment: _Aonde_ também não é grande exemplo de um caso em que a preposição _a_ altera o significado, já que muita a gente a usa por _onde_ (idem para _adonde_, e, antigamente, para _donde_, como no castelhano).

Comment: @Artefacto Bem, que muita gente use, não discordo, mas aprendi como sendo errado e o [dicionário](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/aonde/) ainda não parece ter aceito o uso de *aonde* como sinônimo de *onde*.

Comment: A distinção _onde_ / _aonde_ da norma culta é invenção recente. Pelo menos desde o séc. XVI nunca foi feita consistentemente e em Portugal ninguém segue a norma: ou _aonde_ é visto como marginal e _onde_ é sempre usado ou _aonde_ e _onde_ são usados indistintamente.

Comment: @Artefacto Sim, os dicionários europeus acusam o uso, mas enfatizam ser [não ser indicado](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/685).